# How does a SPARQL endpoint work in a mashup scenario?

Tags: rdf, semantics, sparql

How does a SAPRQL endpoint work, especially when we have a mashup scenario?

For example, I am mashing up two graphs. One is DBpedia and other is LMDB.

Before it executes the SPARQL query, will it load all the datasets from both sources? I guess not.
If not, will it look for matching records in DBpedia or LMDB first?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about using the service keyword in SPARQL, then no, the queries will be answered independently, and then any local operations you do (stuff not in the SERVICE block) will be performed by the executing endpoint.